# tcpdf and locales getnumlines wrong count

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I found annoying error with TCPDF library. Hope you know how help me. I use obj->getNumLines method to calculate how many lines has my text. It works all good in most cases but unfortunatelly not always.I use UTF8 encoding and I use many local signs (I'm from poland and we have a lot of such signs). getNumLines sometimes returns i.e. 5 although multicell displays 6 lines of text.

In my research I found that:

```
$font = $pdf->addTTFfont('/fonts/calibri.ttf', '', '', 32);
$pdf->setFont($font, '', 13)
$string = 'zażółć gęślą jaźń'; (repeated many times)
echo $pdf->getNumLines($string, 0);
```

It prints to the screen different (smaller) number than multicell actually returns lines to the pdf file. I use custom fonts as you can see above, margins are not changed during the code.

Does anybody has idea what is wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: This is probably due the fact that the unicode characters are saved as two bytes, so the character count is not equal to the number of bytes. Check the `mb_*` (eg. `mb_strlen`) functions, they should be used to properly calculate the length. Maybe this depends on PHP your configuration or some bugs in the code.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution maybe?